# How to apply the css for before and after pseudo classes?

Tags: jquery

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nc3PS/)

I have the following html...

```
<div id="q">
  <dl>
    <dt><p>lorem ipsum</p></dt>
    <dd><span>lorem ipsum</span></dd>
    <dd><span>lorem ipsum</span></dd>
    <dd><span>lorem ipsum</span></dd>
    <dd><span>lorem ipsum</span></dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```

And this is extremely required css for my case...

```
#q dd:before{
    content: " ";
    /*height: 65px;*/
}
```

But the height is needed to be created as per the contents as if the height is dynamic. Thus, I need to create it with jQuery....

```
//for test 
var h = '65px';
//problem occurs here
$('#q dd:before').css('height',h);
```

When you inspect it, the height is not added in the `#q dd:before` selector.

Seems `:before` and `:after` pseudo classes are not supported with jQuery.

Do you have any idea with jQuery or javascript?

Comment: Since the pseudo-elements are not real DOM elements, you can't target them with jQuery.

Comment: but :first-child and :last-child are added in jquery what about that?

Comment: Those are pseudo-*classes*, not pseudo-elements. Those classes are used to target *existing*, *real* DOM elements, they don't create pseudo-elements. To make the distinction between pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements better, pseudo-elements are prefixed with `::` in CSS3 instead of `:`.

Comment: @FelixKling your provided answer doesn't answer my question. because that change the content but I need to add height. If you could please answer.

Comment: You have to resort to one of the workarounds mentioned in the other question. They should not only work with `content` but also with other CSS properties.

Comment: that has content to which the content is changed through the attr but how can I have to height?

Comment: NVM, apparently the `attr` CSS function is not supported for values other than string or other properties than `content`, at least not yet.

Comment: so, hopefully my question is not duplicate of that question. please remove that from my question.

Comment: Nope, it's still a duplicate. See this answer for multiple solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21709814/218196. You probably have to resort to "2) Add new styles directly to the document's stylesheet" in that list. I don't think you have gone through of all the answers there yet, haven't you?

Comment: Other answers from the duplicate question that would help are http://stackoverflow.com/a/12952400/218196, http://stackoverflow.com/a/16507274/218196, http://stackoverflow.com/a/12389279/218196

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot target pseudo elements with jQuery, instead you can add a class to the `dd` elements:

```
$('#q dd').addClass('active');
```

then set the style based on this class in your CSS:

```
#q dd.active:before{
    height: 65px;
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nc3PS/1/)**

---

If you want to use dynamic value, then you can set a `<style>` then append it to the `<head>` section:

```
var h = '65px';

$('<style>#q dd:before{height:'+h+'}</style>').appendTo('head');
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nc3PS/4/)**

Comment: height is dynamic so needed to add it with jquery.....